# Flask: Want to import file of helper functions

Tags: python, flask

I'm writing a porting a basic python script and creating a similarly basic Flask application.  I have a file consisting of a bunch of functions that I'd like access to within my Flask application.

Here's what I have so far for my views:

```
from flask import render_template
from app import app

def getRankingList():
    return 'hey everyone!'


@app.route("/")
@app.route("/index")
def index():
    rankingsList = getRankingsList()
    return render_template('index.html', rankingsList = rankingsList)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Ideally, I'd have access to all of the functions from my original script and make use of them within my `getRankingsList()` function.  I've googled around and can't seem to sort out how to do this, however.

Any idea

Comment: It's not any different than importing anything else. Create a `utils.py` (or whatever) and import it or `from utils import foo`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Simply have another python script file (for example `helpers.py`) in the same directory as your main flask .py file.
Then at the top of your main flask file, you can do `import helpers` which will let you access any function in helpers by adding `helpers.` before it (for example `helpers.exampleFunction()`).
Or you can do `from helpers import exampleFunction` and use `exampleFunction()` directly in your code. Or `from helpers import *` to import and use all the functions directly in your code.

Answer (score 13):

Just import your file as usual and use functions from it:

```
# foo.py

def bar():
    return 'hey everyone!'
```

And in the main file:

```
# main.py
from flask import render_template
from app import app
from foo import bar

def getRankingList():
    return 'hey everyone!'


@app.route("/")
@app.route("/index")
def index():
    rankingsList = getRankingsList()
    baz = bar()  # Function from your foo.py
    return render_template('index.html', rankingsList=rankingsList)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```